# Creation of program that controls the menu of other programs

Tags: cmd

I have an application (just like a notepad) that has only run and exit as menus.. all I need is to have a program or a batch file to open the application, select run and then select exit.. please help

Comment: Have you tried AutoHotkey? https://autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) Will do the trick, or [Auto Clicker and typer](http://www.asoftwareplus.com/auto-clicker-typer.html). The former, just make sure to dont accept the extra software bundled in the setup file.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) is a tool that in which you can set up simple scripts that will automate UI actions for you.

Look at the [tutorial](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) to grasp the basics. After that you can use `WinMenuSelectItem` to do as you like:

```
WinMenuSelectItem, Untitled - Notepad, , File, Open
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMenuSelectItem.htm